# How to handle with different dynamic comboboxes?

Tags: jquery

Html

```
<div id="opts" class="styled-select">
 <select id="combo1" class="combo" data-index="1">
        <option></option>
        <option val="Opt1">Opt1</option>
        <option val="Opt2">Opt2</option>
        <option val="Opt3">Opt3</option>
    </select>
</div>



<div id="opts2" class="styled-select">
  <select id="combo2" class="combo2" data-index="1">
            <option></option>
            <option val="Opt11">Opt11</option>
            <option val="Opt22">Opt22</option>
            <option val="Opt32">Opt33</option>
        </select>
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#opts').on('change', '.combo', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
        var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
        var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);
        var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;

        $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

        if (selectedValue !== '') {
            newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
            $('#opts').append(newComboBox);
        }
    }
});​
```

I can't duplicate/use the same code for 2 different comboboxes, it seems to cause some kind of trouble.

How can I have the same "effect" for 2 comboboxes?

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried using `class="combo"` for your second select?

Comment: Yes, but didnt work . You can try it too here: http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/6/

Comment: So what exactly do you want to achieve? I see the elements being cloned and appended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning elements also clone its properties and I have made some changes in your code! check them and see what i have changed :) I wrapped them in a div and some more things!

Jquery:

```
$('body').on('change', '.combo', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
        var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
        var thisComboBoxIndex = $(this).attr('id').replace("combo", "");
        var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 10;

        $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

        if (selectedValue != '') {
            newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
            $('div.'+thisComboBoxIndex).append(newComboBox);
        }
    } 
});​
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="1">
    <select id="combo1" class="combo" data-index="1">
        <option></option>
        <option val="Opt1">Opt1</option>
        <option val="Opt2">Opt2</option>
        <option val="Opt3">Opt3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<div class="2">
    <select id="combo2" class="combo" data-index="2">
        <option></option>
        <option val="Opt1">Opt1</option>
        <option val="Opt2">Opt2</option>
        <option val="Opt3">Opt3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

​
[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/19/)

Comment: Above answer is working 100% but you have to check what i approach i used and to clarify yourself :) :D

Comment: Update: I found a bug there in script and now debugging it sorry for it :D

Comment: Something about "cleaning" the options?

Comment: you want to clean previous option on select of new option?

Comment: I want to clean the options when they are blank. Try to select all options and then turn to blank the 1st options. The following options should be cleaned too

Comment: create an image and with help of some photo editor add comments what you wanna do :/ i can't understand what exactly you want. If you give me image then i can understand better and can provide best code ;) I am waiting :/

Comment: Thanks for being helping me :) look at this http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/6/, select all options and then unselect the 1st option.

Comment: Got it buddy and sit back to get my code :P and it will be better than you i challenge :D you will get your code today at any time, you will get notif!

Comment: well, buddy see this : http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/20/     ! wrapping combobox in a div is compulsory and also give them class in ascending order e.g. 1,2,3,4,5 and so on!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22053/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-skdnewbie)

Comment: Hi buddy, im trying to change that code you made to something new, can you help it ?

Comment: what type of help buddy ? add me on Facebook and message me what you are creating. Search "prefertodie@hotmail.com" in Facebook search and you will get me. Regards, Muhammad Talha Akbar. I can't help you here by just only commenting.

Answer (score 1):

you can use multiselector in `on` function..

```
$('body').on('change', '.combo,.combo2', function() {
```

to make sure your cloned element has unique id , and dat_index...i incresed the value of it

```
var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10) + 1; //here
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/18/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling your function on class selector and both classes of the select boxes are different, So you can try one of the following,

```
<select id="combo1" class="combo" data-index="1">
        <option></option>
        <option val="Opt1">Opt1</option>
        <option val="Opt2">Opt2</option>
        <option val="Opt3">Opt3</option>
    </select>


  <select id="combo2" class="combo" data-index="1">
            <option></option>
            <option val="Opt11">Opt11</option>
            <option val="Opt22">Opt22</option>
            <option val="Opt32">Opt33</option>
        </select>​

$('body').on('change', '.combo', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

if ($(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
    var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
    var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);
    var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;

    $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

    if (selectedValue !== '') {
        newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
        newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex);
        newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
        newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
        $('body').append(newComboBox);
    }
}
});​
```

**or** you can use multiple class selector option

```
$('body').on('change', '.combo,.combo2', function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
        var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
        var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);
        var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;

        $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

        if (selectedValue !== '') {
            newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
            $('body').append(newComboBox);
        }
    }
    });​
```

Comment: thanks, I'm sorry, Ive updated the code, can you check it ? It is my approach correct ?

Answer (score 0):

the setting of class name and Id are the problems.

```
$('body').on('change', '.combo', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

if ($(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
    var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
    //I incremented the index so the new element would have a unique id and class
    var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index')) + 1;
    var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;

    $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

    if (selectedValue !== '') {
        newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
        newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + thisComboBoxIndex.toString());
        newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex.toString());
        newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
        $('body').append(newComboBox);
    }
}
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/2zNRu/1/